Django timeslots not showing up in form
I am trying to build a Django booking system where I am trying to implement the logic that if a timeslot is booked for a certain day, that timeslot should not be clickable (disabled). And beside the timeslot it should read (booked).
This is my implementation.
But my logic is not working. No timeslots are showing up. Can anyone help me point out the problem here? Thanks!
My models.py:
class Timeslot(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    slot_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slot_text

class Appointment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    date = models.DateField()
    timeslot = models.ForeignKey(Timeslot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booked_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} - {self.date} - {self.timeslot.slot_text}"

My views.py:
def check_availability(date):
    timeslots = Timeslot.objects.all()
    booked_timeslots = Appointment.objects.filter(date=date).values_list('timeslot', flat=True)
    available_timeslots = [(timeslot, timeslot.id not in booked_timeslots) for timeslot in timeslots]
    return available_timeslots

def book_appointment(request):
    available_timeslots = []
    form_data = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        date = request.POST.get('date')
        timeslot_id = request.POST.get('timeslot')

        form_data = {
            'name': name,
            'phone': phone,
            'email': email,
            'date': date,
            'timeslot': timeslot_id,
        }

        if 'check_timeslots' in request.POST:
            if date:
                available_timeslots = check_availability(date)
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Please select a date to check available timeslots.')
        elif 'book_appointment' in request.POST:
            if not all([name, phone, email, date, timeslot_id]):
                messages.error(request, 'Please fill out all fields.')
            else:
                timeslot = Timeslot.objects.get(id=timeslot_id)
                existing_appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(date=date, timeslot=timeslot).exists()
                if existing_appointment:
                    messages.error(request, 'The selected timeslot is already booked.')
                    available_timeslots = check_availability(date)
                else:
                    appointment = Appointment.objects.create(
                        name=name,
                        phone=phone,
                        email=email,
                        date=date,
                        timeslot=timeslot
                    )

                    send_mail(
                        subject="Booking Confirmation",
                        message=f"Dear {name},\n\nYour appointment is confirmed for {date} at {timeslot.slot_text}.\n\nThank you!",
                        from_email='your-email@example.com',
                        recipient_list=[email, 'your-email@example.com'],
                        fail_silently=False,
                    )

                    messages.success(request, 'Your appointment has been booked successfully!')
                    return redirect('appointment')

    return render(request, 'appointment/appointment.html', {
        'available_timeslots': available_timeslots,
        'form_data': form_data,
    })

My appointment.html:
<main>
    <!-- breadcrumb-area-start -->
    <section class="breadcrumb-area tpbreadcrumb-overlay" data-background="/static/appointment/assets/img/breadcrumb/breadcrumb-bg-2.jpg" style="background-image: url('/static/appointment/assets/img/breadcrumb/breadcrumb-bg-2.jpg');">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row align-items-center">
             <div class="col-12">
                <div class="tpbreadcrumb text-center">
                   <h2 class="tpbreadcrumb-title">Appointment</h2>
                   <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos <br> ducimus qui blan ditisede voluptatum.</p>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </section>
    <!-- breadcrumb-area-end -->
    
    {% if messages %}
    <div class="container mt-3">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}" role="alert">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <!-- appointment-area-start -->
    <section class="form-area pt-135 pb-65">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-5">
                    <div class="schedules mb-60">
                        <div class="tpsection">
                            <h2 class="tpsection-title mb-35">Weekly Schedule</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="schedules-list">
                            <span>Saturday --------------------------------8am - 5pm</span>
                            <span>Sunday ---------------------------------8am - 5pm</span>
                            <span>Monday -------------------------------- 8am - 5pm</span>
                            <span>Tuesday --------------------------------8am - 5pm</span>
                            <span>Wednesday -----------------------------8am - 5pm</span>
                            <span>Thursday ------------------------------8am - 5pm</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-7">
                    <div class="appoinment-2 appoinment-3 mb-50">
                        <div class="appoinment-2">
                            {% if error %}
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error }}</div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <form method="post" action="{% url 'appointment' %}">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="appoinment-form-input mb-30">
                                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="appoinment-form-input mb-30">
                                            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="appoinment-form-input mb-30">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="appoinment-form-input">
                                            <input type="date" class="doctor-name wide mb-30" name="date" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <div class="appoinment-form-input">
                                            <select class="doctor-name wide mb-30" name="timeslot" required>
                                                <option value="">Select TimeSlot</option>
                                                {% for timeslot, available in timeslots %}
                                                    <option value="{{ timeslot.id }}" {% if not available %}disabled{% endif %}>
                                                        {{ timeslot.slot_text }} {% if not available %}(booked){% endif %}
                                                    </option>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="appoinment-form-submit mb-30">
                                            <button type="submit" class="tp-btn">Get Appointment</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- appointment-area-end -->

    <!-- cta-area-start -->
    <section class="cta-area cta-6-bg pt-100 pb-100" data-background="/static/appointment/assets/img/banner/cta-6-bg-1.jpg" style="background-image: url('/static/appointment/assets/img/banner/cta-6-bg-1.jpg');">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="cta-6-content text-center">
                   <div class="whitesection mb-25">
                      <h2 class="whitesection-title mb-40">Enhance Your Look, <br> Enhance Beauty</h2>
                   </div>
                   <div class="cta-6-btn">
                      <a class="tp-round-btn" href="{% url 'contact' %}">Contact Our Team</a>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </section>
    <!-- cta-area-end -->

</main>


If you add a BooleanField 'is_booked' to your model, you can work with a conditional if statement. You can then use this to check whether a timeslot has already been booked and then output and display it accordingly.
